# UITextField problems in iOS 5 by changing UITextFieldBorderStyle at runtime

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios5

I'm suddenly having trouble with some UITextFields now that I'm testing on iOS 5 devices, even though I built the app in iOS 5 SDK and already let the bug slip through to release.

I have a textfield that allows input, and when you press a "lock" button, it calls:

```
textField.enabled = NO;
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

The Field "hides" but still acts like a label - important function for the app.

Then you press the "lock" button again and it calls:

```
textField.enabled = YES;
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

This works perfectly in 4.2/4.3 but in iOS 5 the only thing that appears is the beveled outline of the textfield with no white background color.

Setting .backgroundColor fixes it on iOS 5 but makes an ugly white square on 4.2/4.3.

I didn't see anything about these changes in the API diffs document, what am I missing here??
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you enabled ARC for your app? It seems that you are trying to access an object that was dealloced.

Comment: yes ARC is on but this is the first time I had this problem. I tried reordering stuff and putting it in front of properties that were working but it didn't make a difference

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same problem! I just created a small project to isolate that problem without changing enabled. I realized that it is a deallocation problem but don't understand why. With NSZombieEnabled I detect a zombie. The weird thing is, that it only happens when switching from `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect` to `UITextBorderStyleNone`. The reverse doesn't crash if the initial border style was set in Storyboard to None. Instead setting the initial value to RoundedRect the app crashes. Seems like the TextField is somehow deallocated.

Comment: @REDMX Any news on this? And I have a question: Which version of XCode are you using? Are you also using the SnowLeopard version(Build: 4C199)? I was thinking if this might be a reason since it doesn't fully support ARC.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with the white background, I fixed this commenting out the line that specifies a background color and setting the opaque property to NO

```
//[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[myTextField setOpaque:NO];
```

This has resolved the issue for both iOS 4.3, and iOS 5.0

-Alex

Comment: Worked for me on both iOS 4.3 and iOS5.0

Answer (score 0):

`userInteractionEnabled` is a property of the much more general `UIView` class, and as such may not behave as you expected with subclasses of `UIControl`, such as `UITextField`. Instead, you should set the `enabled` property to `NO` to temporarily disable a control, which in the case of `UITextField` would do precisely what you want.

Comment: oops - i'm actually using the .enabled property but typed it wrong. I'll change the post, so sadly it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: There's no way your crasher is related to setting the border style or the enabled property -- they're both scalars. So that leaves the text field itself, which in all likelihood is getting deallocated, as Bartosz suggested. Have you tried compiling without ARC on iOS 5?

Comment: turning off ARC didn't fix it sadly

Comment: Can you post the declaration for the `textField` property, as well as any code that's sending a `release` or `autorelease` to it?

Comment: You might also want to show how the object that declares the `textField` property is being managed. It's possible that object is the one being deallocated.

Comment: ok thanks, the BAD_ACCESS is solved now, I made a typo in the property declaration. Thanks for pointing that out.  The problem with the rounded rect not coming back is still happening.  I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

A possible fix is to set `alpha` to `0.00001`. That gives you effectively hidden labels which can still respond to control events.

Comment: issue is I need the text to be visible just like a label

Comment: In that case, just set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`. Or copy the `text` into an actual `UILabel` (or `UITextView` would be the more appropriate for multiline text) which you then unhide.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem, and the UITextBorderStyleNone was working fine in iOS 4.3, but on iOS 5 is stopped working. I think this is a bug from Apple, because it doesn't work on both the device and the simulator. I think your best shot here is to switch between the label and the text field as needed like darvids0n suggests till Apple solves the bug.