# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when Switching between UITextBorderStyleNone and RoundRect on UITextField

Tags: ios5, uitextfield, xcode4.2

I cannot figure out a way to switch back and forth between two different border styles on a TextField during run time without crashing the application.

I know how to code it (shown below):

```
- (void)switchToStaticView
{
    [nameTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

    // rest of code snipped out
}

- (void)switchToEditView
{
    [nameTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

    // rest of code snipped out
}
```

I get a 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' error when going back to StyleNone. I believe this is an issue with IOS5 and/or Xcode 4.2 - Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: There is nothing here that stands out. How is `nameTextField` defined? Are you using ARC? Is it a property or just an ivar?

Comment: Yes I'm using ARC, its defined as a property not an iVar... 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;

Answer (score 0):

Change the property definition to a strong reference

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
```

Weak references are used to stop a circular reference. Read more [ARC Lifetime Qualifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html)

Comment: changing it to strong did not solve the issue, I'm still getting the same error when trying to go back to UITextBorderStyleNone. Funny thing is if I change the switchToEditView method to use UITextBorderStyleBezel instead of RoundedRect it works perfectly and without issue! Weird!...

Comment: I just found another thread, these people are also having the same issue as I am, no resolution to the issue in this thread however... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759729/uitextfield-problems-in-ios-5-by-changing-uitextfieldborderstyle-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your background color right before you set the border style - inserting:`titleTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` fixed it for me.  (via [UITextView setBorderStyle crashes in iOS 5 Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783330/uitextview-setborderstyle-crashes-in-ios-5-simulator))